# PHP displays output while executing script working on local not on live server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, nginx, server

I want to display output after curl execution calling inside a loop here's an example

```
echo "Hello!";
flush();
ob_flush();

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i ++) {
echo $i;
$res = file_get_contents('https://www.example.com');

//5-10 sec execution time
flush();
ob_flush();
}
```

This example works fine on local but not on live server , Because of nginx default output buffering on ,How can i control this n where to edit all configuration on files, and what could be the best possiblesolution for this ?

Comment: Nginx or apache? You have both tags

Comment: @AlexeyTen phpinfo says apache but some article says it is bydefault set in nginx So even i am not sure.

Comment: How could you be not sure of what web server you use?

Comment: @AlexeyTen $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'] is apache but here's an article "https://www.sitepoint.com/php-streaming-output-buffering-explained/" that says it could be a problem of nginx server